# php 5.6 spl_autoload_register not working

Tags: php

```
<?php
function __autoload($className) {
    echo $className;exit;
}
new Demo();
```

it works above.

```
<?php
function autoload($className) {
    echo $className;exit;
}
spl_autoload_register('autoload');
new Demo();
```

it's not work, Fatal error: Class 'Demo' not found.

Enviroment:
CentOS 6 + php 5.6

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks very much

Comment: Here on `PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17` the first gets a Fatal Error, the second work :) But since you never load the class you will get always:`Fatal error: Class 'Demo' not found.`

Comment: It seems that this is some interal PHP behavior, but since you see always `Demo` from your `print` everthing is ok.

Comment: Maybe that helps: `Guys, this document ( i mean __autoload() ) not mentioned one special situation: if you both use __autoload() and spl_autoload_register(), the __autoload() function will never to be called.` http://php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php#114700